# Javascript Game Of Life. Return to initial stage on Clear all

Tags: javascript

How to set matrix to initial stage by **clearAll** Button?

```
const clearAll = () => {
const tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
const ck = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
const totalcells = tds.length
  for (let k = 0; k <= totalcells; k++){  
    ck[k].checked = false
    tds[k].style.background = "#fff"
    if (!running) {
    running = false
    }
  }
  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anoops7776/6qpa9bfx/37/

Comment: Hiding relevant details behind a link doesn’t help. What is the initial stage of the matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by initial stage?

Comment: For 'clear all' all cells should - unchecked, cells in white color, play function should stop if I clicked clearall while play is running

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have running set to false in clearAll function only if it is already false. `if (!running) {running = false}` will never set running to false if running is true. You actually don't need the conditional, since you want `running` to be `false` irrespective of its current value, so just use `running = false`

Original version:

```
    const clearAll = () => {
      const tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
      const ck = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      const totalcells = tds.length
    
      for (let k = 0; k <= totalcells; k++){  
        ck[k].checked = false
        tds[k].style.background = "#fff"
        if (!running) {
          running = false
        }
      }
      
    }
```

Modified version with running always set to false:

```
    const clearAll = () => {
      running = false
      const tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td")
      const ck = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      const totalcells = tds.length
      for (let k = 0; k <= totalcells; k++){  
        ck[k].checked = false
        tds[k].style.background = "#fff"
      }
    }
```

See cloned fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/md04k53j/ to see it work.